# Why @transactional annotation is not recommend to be used with select operation

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, transactional

I am new to spring.

Why is the `@transactional` annotation not recommend to be used with the select operation?

Comment: Where is the source of your assumption?

Comment: `@Transactional` is used for an operation that can modify the data, not for read operations.

Comment: @NicholasK That is incorrect, `@Transactional` can also be used for read only operations. And selects are also transactional, and can select different records (or even block) depending on the isolation level and database specific transaction handling.

Comment: In fact it is better to use `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` for select only ops when your connection has auto commit turned off as this will give a lot of warnings...

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the @transactional annotation not recommend to be used with the select operation?

Not true, You didn't provide a proof for such recommendation (please do) and in [Spring @Transactional settings](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings) you have select or read only transaction support

> ```
> readOnly  boolean  Read/write vs. read-only transaction
> ```

Also when using connection pool if you don't rollback/commit after select statement it will consider it as dirty commit, for example see [Hikari's brettwooldridge comment](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1051)

> if autoCommit=false you absolutely must call commit() or rollback() in order to ensure correctness.

Answer (score -1):

Select Operation is about reading, there is nothing Transactional about it.  Transactional usually refers to bundling a number of writes to DB in a single Atomic unit.  If the Transaction fails the entire unit, with all the bundled writes, are rollbacked.  So a transaction can only succeed if all the statements in the transaction pass.

Select is a read only operation.  For Select you can have things like - Read Dirty or Read after Commit etc. but transactional does not apply.

Comment: This is incorrect, even selects are executed in a transaction, if only to determine visibility of changes, lock behavior and isolation for reading modified records, etc. If you were correct, why would `@Transactional` even have a `readOnly` attribute?

Comment: If you read my entire comment, I have mentioned it in another way that Read Dirty or Read After Commits are strategies defined, but not transactional.

Comment: And that comment is incorrect: that is not how it actually works.